# Subversion and symlinks on Windows for WordPress development

Tags: windows, wordpress, symlink

I'd like to use the method described here to use subversion for WordPress development:

http://www.aaronwhitman.com/2010/01/subversion-repository-with-wordpress-external/

Does anyone know whether linkd.exe will do the job for the symlinking part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

linkd.exe and mklink can do this. Linkd.exe can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en)

mklink is available as standard on windows 2008. Note that mklink requires the /D argument specifically for symlinking folders